# "Vite manifest not found" due to traffic, during deployment

Tags: laravel, vite, manifest.json

First of all, I've read all the other questions suggested by SO, but none of them solve the situation I'm in, or if they come close, they don't provide an adequate answer.

For context, I'm working on a Laravel 8 project initially using Mix, but recently migrated to Vite.

We do not commit the `/public/build` folder to Github.

Instead, we placed the command `npm run prod` (which map to `vite build` in the `package.json`) in the Forge deployment script, and everything goes well.

The problem is that when there is traffic on the site, if a page is called during the fraction of seconds that the `manifest.json` file is regenerated, this error pops-up in the logs and in Sentry :

```bash
Vite manifest not found at: /home/forge/<myproject>/public/build/manifest.json
```

For the user, it results in an `Error 500`, which is very annoying.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: share the `vite.config.js` file

Comment: My bad. did not see the `traffic` part. Can you put your page in maintenance mode then generate the manifest.json?

Comment: So that users wont access these files when building

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already suggested it to my superiors, but the response was that they didn't want to put the site in maintenance mode during deployments. I agree that this would be the best solution, and I'm going to ask for more explanation on "why" they don't want it. In the meantime, if anyone has another suggestion, I'll take it.

Comment: I'am also looking at the best solution for this. Was considering maintenance mode, but that would make the app inaccessible during the deployment (1 min) which is not really wanted.

Comment: @TwystO did you solve this in any other way than setting to maintenance mode? Maybe ViteJS could keep the files until the new files are generated?

Comment: @5less I added an answer, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to get rid of this of this error by using the `reportable` method in the `register` function of `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

As documented here ([Reporting Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#reporting-exceptions)) simply add :

```php
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // ...

    // Exclude this annoying 'Vite manifest not found' exception from logs.
    $this->reportable(function (\Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Exceptions\ViewException $e) {
        if (Str::of($e->getMessage())->contains('Vite manifest not found')) {
            return false; // or anything else for that matter
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

And that's it, the error stop being logged.

But at this point I haven't made tests to check if still shows error 500 to the user.

Also, another way (perhaps more reliable or at least elegant) could be to define `report` and `render` methods directly on your application's exceptions.

It's documented here ([Renderable Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#renderable-exceptions))